# How a chrome extension can write something in a textbook in calendar?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am the beginner for the chrome extension, I want to develop a simple function now.

I want to write something to the textbox in the calendar likes photo[image: textbox]

perhaps it is not named textbook, so I add a photo here.

I have some questions:
1. how can i use *.js to detect the textbox?
2. how to write something in it automatic?

Could you poste some codes to understand better? Thank you.

I hava a *.js to inverse the text, but i don't really understand it 100%, could you explain it to me? thank you.

```
 // Called when the url of a tab changes.
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

  if (tab.url.indexOf('calendar') > -1) {

         chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {code: '.ui-sch input { direction: rtl }'});
         chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {code: '.ui-sch textarea { direction: rtl }'});
  }
};

// Listen for any changes to the URL of any tab.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

Comment: Nobody knows this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this answer, we can do this by search his ID and write somethings in it